# Logic App returning empty object from WSDL-imported SOAP route

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl, azure-logic-apps

So I want to make a login request against a SOAP API. EDIT: [This WSDL](https://api.cvent.com/soap/V200611.ASMX?WSDL).

Here's what a successful login looks like, via plain old POST (sent via Postman, no interaction with Logic Apps):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    ...
    <soap:Body>
        <LoginResponse xmlns="http://api.xxx.com/">
            <LoginResult 
                LoginSuccess="true" 
                ServerURL="xxx://xxx.ASMX" 
                sessionHeader="token" 
                ErrorMessage="" 
                xmlns="xxx://xxx" />
        </LoginResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The most important part is the `sessionHeader` attribute on `<LoginResult>` which is the token required by any further requests against the API.

Now I take a WSDL for the same API and I import it as a Logic App Custom Connector. It imports just fine and the `login` route appears to be correct. It asks for the relevant information (username, login, account id, etc). When I use the login route in a Logic App, however, this is the result:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        ....
    },
    "body": {
        "loginResponse": {
            "loginResult": {}
        }
    }
}
```

It's the same basic structure as the XML above, but all of the attributes have been stripped out. I need those attributes because that's where the token is. So:

1) Can I somehow get the connector/logic app to return attributes? Is it already returning them and I just don't know where they are?

2) Is returning the token as an attribute not the way it should be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the schema for LoginResponse in the WSDL?  Is the POST also from a LogicApp?  Meaning the difference is the Custom Connector.

Comment: I _think_ I addressed your questions with some edits. Briefly, POST request is via Postman, no Logic App involved. Schema for Login Response is in WSDL, I think.